# Windows Azure web role useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" not working getting "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I know that this post may look like a duplicate but i have **tried every solution** method around the internet & StackOverflow and i have still no idea about how to fix it.

I am trying to do simple get into some other Linux-PHP System from Windows Azure web role, and I get 
"The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"

On my local Machine it works But On Production inside Windows Azure it's NOT :-(.

I had verified that the loaded assembly are correct, the framework version is correct.

What I had tried to do:

I have tried adding this to my web.config

```
<system.net>
 <settings>
   <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing ="true"/>
 </settings>
```

**didn't work at all.**

Tried adding these :

```
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
request.KeepAlive = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 99999;
```

**didn't work at all.**

I had tried to use http://restsharp.org/  to do the request
**didn't work at all.**

I had tried to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/  to do the request
**didn't work at all.**

I had Tried to use `HttpClient Class` to do the call

**didn't work at all.**

Tried This solution [The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747973/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-in-c-sharp)
**didn't work at all.**

Tried to Set the property  useUnsafeHeaderParsing via [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424144/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-in-code).
**didn't work at all.**

Tried so many things for more than 10 hours with no results.... 
Still not working Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Alter Digging and digging and trying variant solution I had found the Issue!!!**

The issue was that there was a firewall in front of this Linux-PHP machine, 
that was providing totally misinformed response with a a bizarre text-html message.

So the issue was that the .NET return an **Incorrect**  Response.

So The Step that worked:
**Check that the remote host or url is not blocked on the firewall!**